NFS mixup with mounted ISO images
I have made an offline Debian software repository with currently 49 DVD images on my NAS. I created a single directory '/mnt/ISO-images' which contains the 49 mountpoints. I export this single directory with NFS to my newly installed Debian desktops. But I find that sometimes the contents of DVD images get mixed up as seen from my desktops (when I access DVD-X I see the contents of DVD-Y), while the contents seems OK when checking it locally on the NAS. With further testing I also found that sharing the same directory '/mnt/ISO-images' over SMB goes fine: when I browse the contents of DVD X I always get the right contents.
So in summary: when I browse the contents of DVDs over SMB or locally, on the NAS, I get what I expect. If I browse the same DVDs over NSF the contents of DVD's sometimes gets mixed up.
Here's basically my ISO-mount-over-NFS setup, with DVD-1, 2 & 3 for Debian 12.5 AMD64 as an example:
Desktop setup:

in /etc/apt/sources.list:

deb [trusted=yes] file:/mnt/Repo/Deb-12.5/AMD_01/ bookworm main contrib
deb [trusted=yes] file:/mnt/Repo/Deb-12.5/AMD_02/ bookworm main contrib
deb [trusted=yes] file:/mnt/Repo/Deb-12.5/AMD_03/ bookworm main contrib


in /etc/fstab:

# NFS share for Debian repo for APT package manager
Nassie01:/mnt/ISO-images /mnt/Repo nfs4 _netdev 0  0

Note that I use a single mount for the remote directory which contains all the subdirs with ISO-images mounted, so no mixup of DVD images can take place at this point.
NAS setup:

First I create a short named symlink, f.e. DVD_01 --> Debian-12.5.0-amd64-DVD-1.iso
Then I create a second symlink higher up the folder hierarchy so I can work with shorter names in 'fstab', f.e. AMD_01 --> long/path/name/DVD_01
Then I mount the ISO image in '/etc/fstab' like this:

/mnt/NAS/Install/ISO-links/Deb-12.5/AMD_01 /mnt/ISO-images/Deb-12.5/AMD_01  udf,iso9660 ...,mode=0444,loop,ro,...


Then I publish it with NFS in '/etc/exports':

/mnt/ISO-images     192.168.144.0/23(ro,crossmnt,no_root_squash)

Notes: 'ro' makes the export read only (just as a real DVD would be); 'crossmnt' makes the contents of the DVDs (in fact: whats behind the 49 mountpoints) visible over the NFS connection; 'no_root_squash' allows Aptitude (which normally is executed by 'root') to access the contents of '/mnt/ISO-images').
Problem examples when using NFS v4:
I present two examples where things go wrong. In the first example, where I mount ISOs for ARM 32-bit architecture (used for my Raspberry Pis), the problem is already clear from the output of the 'mount' command (to show the active mounts) on my desktop:
Nassie01:/mnt/ISO-images/Deb-12.5/AHF_01 on /mnt/Repo/Deb-12.5/AHF_01 type nfs4 ...
Nassie01:/mnt/ISO-images/Deb-12.5/AHF_02 on /mnt/Repo/Deb-12.5/AHF_02 type nfs4 ...
Nassie01:/mnt/ISO-images/Deb-12.5/AHF_01 on /mnt/Repo/Deb-12.5/AHF_03 type nfs4 ...

In this case I can't explain why AHF_01 is reported to be mounted to AHF_01 and AHF_03 while on the NAS it's only mounted to AHF_01. But given this situation I can understand that I get a different DVD contents on the desktop and the NAS.
The same problem happens with another distro, a 64 bit AMD DVD collection for Debian 11.4, but even stranger because the 'mount' command reports nothing wrong:
Nassie01:/mnt/ISO-images/Deb-11.4/AMD_01 on /mnt/Repo/Deb-11.4/AMD_01 type nfs4 ...
Nassie01:/mnt/ISO-images/Deb-11.4/AMD_02 on /mnt/Repo/Deb-11.4/AMD_02 type nfs4 ...
Nassie01:/mnt/ISO-images/Deb-11.4/AMD_03 on /mnt/Repo/Deb-11.4/AMD_03 type nfs4 ...

But still, in this case the local directory AMD_03 on the desktop shows the contents of remote directory AMD_09 on the NAS:
On the desktop, over NFS (incorrect):
$ cd /mnt/Repo/Deb-11.4/AMD_01 ; grep Official README.txt
      Debian GNU/Linux 11.4.0 "Bullseye" - Official amd64 DVD Binary-1
      Debian GNU/Linux 11.4.0 "Bullseye" - Official amd64 DVD Binary-1
$ cd ../AMD_02 ; grep Official README.txt
      Debian GNU/Linux 11.4.0 "Bullseye" - Official amd64 DVD Binary-2
      Debian GNU/Linux 11.4.0 "Bullseye" - Official amd64 DVD Binary-2
$ cd ../AMD_03 ; grep Official README.txt
      Debian GNU/Linux 11.4.0 "Bullseye" - Official amd64 DVD Binary-9
      Debian GNU/Linux 11.4.0 "Bullseye" - Official amd64 DVD Binary-9

On request of @Aviro (thanx!) I add this info:
$ df /mnt/Repo/Deb-11.4/AMD_0{1,2,3}/README.txt
Bestandssysteem                          1K-blokken Gebruikt Beschikbaar Geb% Aangekoppeld op
Nassie01:/mnt/ISO-images/Deb-11.4/AMD_01    3810048  3810048           0 100% /mnt/Repo/Deb-11.4/AMD_01
Nassie01:/mnt/ISO-images/Deb-11.4/AMD_02    4574464  4574464           0 100% /mnt/Repo/Deb-11.4/AMD_02
Nassie01:/mnt/ISO-images/Deb-11.4/AMD_03    4583232  4583232           0 100% /mnt/Repo/Deb-11.4/AMD_03
$ readlink -f /mnt/Repo/Deb-11.4/AMD_0{1,2,3}/README.txt
/mnt/Repo/Deb-11.4/AMD_01/README.txt
/mnt/Repo/Deb-11.4/AMD_02/README.txt
/mnt/Repo/Deb-11.4/AMD_03/README.txt

On the NAS (as expected):
$ cd /mnt/ISO-images/Deb-11.4/AMD_01 ; grep Official README.txt
      Debian GNU/Linux 11.4.0 "Bullseye" - Official amd64 DVD Binary-1
      Debian GNU/Linux 11.4.0 "Bullseye" - Official amd64 DVD Binary-1
$ cd ../AMD_02 ; grep Official README.txt
      Debian GNU/Linux 11.4.0 "Bullseye" - Official amd64 DVD Binary-2
      Debian GNU/Linux 11.4.0 "Bullseye" - Official amd64 DVD Binary-2
$ cd ../AMD_03 ; grep Official README.txt
      Debian GNU/Linux 11.4.0 "Bullseye" - Official amd64 DVD Binary-3
      Debian GNU/Linux 11.4.0 "Bullseye" - Official amd64 DVD Binary-3

On request of @Aviro (thanx!) I add this info:
# df /mnt/ISO-images/Deb-11.4/AMD_0{1,2,3}/README.txt
Filesystem     1K-blocks    Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/loop45      3810016 3810016         0 100% /mnt/ISO-images/Deb-11.4/AMD_01
/dev/loop41      4574430 4574430         0 100% /mnt/ISO-images/Deb-11.4/AMD_02
/dev/loop35      4349704 4349704         0 100% /mnt/ISO-images/Deb-11.4/AMD_03
# readlink -f /mnt/ISO-images/Deb-11.4/AMD_0{1,2,3}/README.txt
/mnt/ISO-images/Deb-11.4/AMD_01/README.txt
/mnt/ISO-images/Deb-11.4/AMD_02/README.txt
/mnt/ISO-images/Deb-11.4/AMD_03/README.txt

When I revert back from NFS to SMB I get the same, correct, results as locally on the NAS. I tried this on three NASses, two Intel based and one RPi based. They all give this problem, but not always with the same DVD images.
My point here: if I had made mistakes while creating symlinks on the NAS, it would have shown both on the desktop and on the NAS. But in my case, the mixup only shows on the desktop and only over NFS, not over SMB. So my NFS setup (or a bug in NFS) is my main suspect.
Further info: my desktops run Debian 12.5 AMD64 with the 'nfs-common' client package installed, my main NASses run Debian 10.2 AMD64 with 'nfs-kernel-server' installed. Note that, so far, I only found the problem on my special "Repo <=> ISO-image" share. My other NFS shares (for normal data, backups, (multi)media, etc, all w/o ISO mount constructs) work fine.
I've strong indications that all my NASses suffer from this bug "https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=867067" (which forces me to issue a 'systemctl restart nfs-kernel-server' every time after a reboot of my NASses). This bug has been around for a while, but I'm not sure if it has anything to do with my mixup problem.
My questions: Does anyone has a clue of what's going wrong here? Can a chain of symlinks combined with ISO mounts on the NFS server give mixups on an NFS client (I tested with both relative and absolute symlinks on the NAS but the results were the same)? Does anyone have had the same problems? Does anyone know how to correct or prevent the problem?

Please run the following commands to show if the areas are mounted and what is the absolute path to your README files: df /mnt/ISO-images/Deb-11.4/AMD_0{1,2,3}/README.txt and readlink -f /mnt/ISO-images/Deb-11.4/AMD_0{1,2,3}/README.txt. Please [edit] your question and add the output of those commands on both your NAS and your desktop.

Does the output of your df come from the NAS server, or from your desktop? Because if it's from your desktop, you can see it isn't NFS...

@Aviro, I've added the requested output from both the desktop (/mnt/Repo) and the server (/mnt/ISO-images). In addition I synchronized my backup NAS with my primary NAS and switched roles. After a reboot of the backup NAS I had to issue 'systemctl restart nfs-kernel-server' to make the NFS shares available (backup NAS also runs Debian 10.2 AMD64 so probably is affected by the same bug as the primary NAS). I then changed my mount commands in fstab on my desktop, rebooted it and connected to my backup NAS.

@Aviro,  I now have similar problems with some symlinks opening the wrong DVD image, but the redirection failures are not identical(!). In summary, on primary NAS:


/mnt/Repo/Deb-11.4/AMD_03 => DVD-9
/mnt/Repo/Deb-11.4/AMD_04 => DVD-16
/mnt/Repo/Deb-11.4/AMD_17 => DVD-6
/mnt/Repo/Deb-11.4/AMD_18 => DVD-6
/mnt/Repo/Deb-12.5/AHF_03 => DVD-1
/mnt/Repo/Deb-12.5/AMD_10 => DVD-11
/mnt/Repo/Deb-12.5/AMD_12 => DVD-11
/mnt/Repo/Deb-12.5/ARM_10 => DVD-11
/mnt/Repo/Deb-12.5/ARM_12 => DVD-11


In summary, on backup NAS:

/mnt/Repo/Deb-11.4/AMD_03 => DVD-9
/mnt/Repo/Deb-11.4/AMD_04 => DVD-16
/mnt/Repo/Deb-11.4/AMD_06 => DVD-18
/mnt/Repo/Deb-11.4/AMD_17 => DVD-18
/mnt/Repo/Deb-12.5/AHF_01 => DVD-3
/mnt/Repo/Deb-12.5/AMD_11 => DVD-10
/mnt/Repo/Deb-12.5/AMD_12 => DVD-10
/mnt/Repo/Deb-12.5/ARM_11 => DVD-10
/mnt/Repo/Deb-12.5/ARM_12 => DVD-10


Mind you! I synchronized '/mnt/ISO-images' using 'rsync' so primary and backup directory should be identical. And this is proved by the 'grep' commands I've issued on the backup NAS. But the 'grep' commands on the desktop (linked to backup NAS) show errors and they are similar but not identical to those when my desktop was linked to the primary NAS. Any ideas?!

In the meantime I will also synchronize my Intel NAS with my offsite disaster recovery NAS (which is an RPi running Debian 10.2 ARM64 and doesn't seem to suffer from mentioned NFS bug). But this might take me some time.

@SteijnvanEssen your synchronisation with rsync isnt using the NFS/SMB mounts is it. For efficiency you should be using either rsync over ssh or rsync over its own rsync daemon. And at least the -t flag to copy file modification times

@Chris Davies I don't use the NFS/SMB mounts as connection for synchronizing. They are only the source and target. Since I don't recall configuring the use of SSH I guess I use the rsync daemon (and its TCP ports) for transport. This is my full syntax:

rsync -ahv --delete --password-file=<PW_file>  

where  point to a local directoy and  starts with @<dest_hostname> and  is equal to <PW_file> on the local and remote server

the '-a' flag covers '-rlptgoD' so yes, '-t' is included (and '-l' as well, to maintain symlinks as they are). And the symlinks copied with 'rsync' work flawless on the dest host and just the same as on the source host.

Your question is so long and has so many details and text (which you just keep adding to with new updates every couple of days), I really doubt if anyone would spend the time and effort to read it through. If I were you, I would try to be as concise as possible, remove all the irrelevant text and information (I don't care why you use NFS, or if it works on SMB, it's just a distraction), and just try to summarize the current state with only the relevant details and stay to the point.

No to mention I have no idea what post #780043 means.

@Aviro and others: I got the message. I stopped working on post # 780043 and added its new information here. Then I tried to clean up this post a bit. But please, don't kill me for adding info on SMB. I think this info supports my suspicion about NFS being the source of my problem and not some misconfiguration with symlinks.
